# Multiplatform String Management Tool (Android & iOS)

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

I'm looking for a tool in order to manage the strings of an app, allowing to maintain the same string both in Android and iOS with an export option or something similar.

Is there something like that?

Comment: Check out http://labelmanager.mobi/
It's a great solution for dealing with this issue. It provides plugins for Android Studio and Xcode and has a role based system to limited the actions for translators, developers, admins etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question seems similar to [Localize multi plattform projects - Consolidate string-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324967/localize-multi-plattform-projects-consolidate-string-files/20330497#20330497)

For my own project I've made an Excel spreadsheet with VBA macro, you can download example here:

http://members.home.nl/bas.de.reuver/files/multilanguage.zip

Answer (score 0):

we're using http://www.getlocalization.com. The tool also provides professional translation services, but you don't have to use that. It also lets you invite multiple translators, or even crowd-source your translations. All identical strings are shared between multiple platforms, so a translation for your iOS project automatically will show up in your Android project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [transai](https://github.com/Jintin/transai) to manage your translation for both Android and iOS.

Simple three step:

**1. install:**

```
    $ sudo npm install transai -g
```

**2. extract strings to csv format:**

```
    $ transai load -a <android_path> -i <ios_path> --from <lang1> --to <lang2> -c <csv_path>
```

**3. restore csv file to your projects:**

```
    $ transai save -a <android_path> -i <ios_path> --from <lang1> --to <lang2> -c <csv_path>
```

for more information, please visit https://github.com/Jintin/transai