# How to handle partially translated Localizable.strings file

Tags: ios, localization

I have a **Localizable.strings (base)** file with, for example, the following strings:

> "hello_world" = "Hello World"; 
>   "hello_world2" = "Hello World";

It is being translated to multiple languages. So I also have the following:

- **Localizable.strings (Chinese (Simplified))**
- **Localizable.strings (Russian)**
- and etc.

Now the problem is that as the project grows, we have more and more new strings being added. But we don't want to wait for the translators to fully translate all the strings before we ship the app. Therefore, we end of having this **Localizable.strings (Chinese (Simplified))** where `hello_world2` is missing:

> "hello_world" = "你好世界";

By default, the not translated string will be shown as the key "hello_world2" in the app. **The question: is there a way to say, if a translation of key "hello_world2" doesn't exist, use the base translation instead?**

---

Additional Info:

I know that for *storyboard* file, if it is partially translated, then it will just use the base translation for not translated strings. However, the same (nice) behaviour doesn't happen for other general *.strings* file. Really looking for a elegant way to solve this issue.

Comment: Why not just fill in the missing text keys in the Chinese .strings file with the English texts? Requires no additional code.

Comment: @BdR, thanks for the suggestion! Yes, this is a option. But we have many strings and supports many languages (current 5 but more in the future for sure). So I hope there is a more automatic way to handle the issue other than asking the developer to fill in the strings for all languages whenever a new strings is added (or modified).

Comment: How do you manage your translations then, just editing the .strings files? If so, then maybe take a look at this question over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324967/localize-multi-plattform-projects-consolidate-string-files/20330497#20330497

Comment: @BdR, Since Xcode 6, strings file, storyboard file, and xib file are exported for translation as xliff file. And then we upload the xliff file to some site for the translators to translate. After they are done, we download the strings and import it back to Xcode. The benefit of using xliff and external tools (such as [OneSkyApp](http://www.oneskyapp.com/), [POEditor](https://poeditor.com/) and etc. )  is that we can handle multiple platforms and migration problems easily. So question is more about what can we do if the translation is not yet done, but we want to release the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the easiest way to cope with this is to use the default string as the key. So you might have:

Base:

```
"Hello World" = "Hello World"; 
"Hello World 2" = "Hello World 2";
```

Chinese:

```
"Hello World" = "Hello World in Chinese";
```

If you haven't made any translations you just need to have at least one placeholder string in the file to avoid a compilation error, e.g. for a double space:

Russian:

```
/* Placeholder */
"  " = "  ";
```

It also makes the translator's job much easier!

Comment: I think this is the right approach. For "... you just need to have at least one placeholder string in the file to avoid a compilation error", in this case, I would just remove this language entirely for the app.