# How do I propagate changes from my main strings.xml to localized copies?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, localization

I created a localized copy of strings.xml and translated some strings. However, I went back to my main strings.xml to make some changes. Is there an easy way to propagate the changes to all downstream translated xml files without losing the translation?

Android Studio 1.3.2

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

e.g.
original strings.xml

```
<string name="order_summary_name">"Name: "</string>
```

original zh/strings.xml

```
<string name="order_summary_name">"名字: "</string>
```

modified strings.xml

```
<!--
  Name for the order summary. It will be shown in the format of "Name: Amy" where Amy is the
  user's name. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE]
-->
<string name="order_summary_name">Name: <xliff:g id="orderName" example="Amy">%s</xliff:g></string>
```

---

EDIT: @BdR Looks like there's no first party Android Studio method to propagate localization changes downstream. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done this is keep track of all strings in a separate spreadsheet, and then generate all the strings.xml files from there using a macro.

That way you can update edit and insert strings more easily, because it easy to remove a line or spot blank cells.

See my [example Excel file](http://members.home.nl/bas.de.reuver/files/multilanguage.zip) or see [question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324967/localize-multi-plattform-projects-consolidate-string-files/20330497#20330497) for more details.