# Listing missing language files

Tags: ios, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have this project localized in several languages. Xcode shows the following list of files:

[image]

You can see that some languages have more files than others. Is there a way to list what files are missing on each language?

Yes, I know that I can use the parameter `-NSShowNonLocalizedStrings YES` as an argument passed on launch. I did that but that is not showing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an indirect answer to your question; If you have that many `.strings` files you might want to organise them more structurally.

You could put all translatable strings in either a database or a spreadsheet and generate your source files from there. This may sound like more work but I think in the end it saves time.

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324967/localize-multi-plattform-projects-consolidate-string-files/20330497#20330497) about consolidating strings files. Or see [my example spreadsheet](http://members.home.nl/bas.de.reuver/files/stringsconvert.html) to manage your localisations and spot missing texts more easily.